# Time is showing as decimal in office 365

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, office365

I am exporting the time columns to excel using NPOI. It works perfectly in excel 2010. But in office 365 after some rows, excel is showing time as decimal numbers. I am formatting the time using '[h]:mm;@' format and no time values are greater than 24.

```
Dim Style As ICellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle    
Dim df As IDataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat
Style.DataFormat = df.GetFormat("[h]:mm;@")
cell.SetCellFormula("TIME(" + ts2.Hours.ToString + "," +             
s2.Minutes.ToString + ",0)")
cell.SetCellType(CellType.Formula)
cell.CellStyle.BorderBottom = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium
cell.CellStyle.BorderLeft = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium
cell.CellStyle.BorderRight = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium
cell.CellStyle.BorderTop = NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium    
Dim evaluator As IFormulaEvaluator = 
workbook.GetCreationHelper.CreateFormulaEvaluator 
evaluator.EvaluateFormulaCell(cell)
cell.CellStyle = Style
```

The result is as below

```
6:51        14:51 

6:51        14:51

7:00        0.541666667  

0.875     0.333333333

0.285416667       0.61875
```

Comment: Dates in COM, VB6 and Excel *are* stored as decimals. The integer part is an offset from `1899-12-31` and the fractional part represents the time of day. If you see the raw value it means that the cell's style is not date-related